# selecting from an object with a complex list to only get items that are in another list (linq)

Tags: c#, linq

I've seen many similar examples but I cant piece this particular situation together from other questions  or the MS documentation.

How would I accomplish the following given these objects?

I would like to perform a LINQ query to give me only those product items in 'product' that have categories that are in 'userSelectedCategories' this example should give me two products (ID = 1 & ID = 2)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<string> userSelectedCategories = new List<string>();
            userSelectedCategories.Add("1");
            userSelectedCategories.Add("3");

            Product product1 = new Product() { ID = 1 };
            product1.Categories = new List<Category>();
            product1.Categories.Add(new Category() { CategoryID = 1, Name = "Blue" });
            product1.Categories.Add(new Category() { CategoryID = 2, Name = "Yellow" });
            product1.Categories.Add(new Category() { CategoryID = 3, Name = "Green" });
            product1.Categories.Add(new Category() { CategoryID = 4, Name = "Purple" });

            Product product2 = new Product() { ID = 2 };
            product2.Categories = new List<Category>();
            product2.Categories.Add(new Category() { CategoryID = 1, Name = "Blue" });
            product2.Categories.Add(new Category() { CategoryID = 2, Name = "Yellow" });

            Product product3 = new Product() { ID = 3 };
            product3.Categories = new List<Category>();
            product3.Categories.Add(new Category() { CategoryID = 2, Name = "Yellow" });    
            
        }
    }

    public class Product
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public List<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    }

    public class Category
    {
        public int CategoryID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try sth like the following:

```
var result = (from product in products
             let categories = product.Categories.Select(x=>x.CategoryID.ToString())
             where categories.Any(category => userSelectedCategories.Contains(category)
             select product)
            .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

What I ended up having to do was very close to @Christos answer:

```
query = (from product in query
             let categories = product.Categories.Select(x => x.CategoryID.ToString())
             where categories.Any(category => userSelectedCategories.Contains(category))
             select product);
```

Comment: You are correct, missed the projection, `select`.